# Stop objects from being selected

Tags: objects, selection-tools

I have some reference meshes in some scenes, That are holding the shape for what I'm molding. The issue though is I keep accidentally selecting them, and it is driving me crazy :), So how can I **stop these objects from being selected.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select the object in the outliner and click the white arrow

*Note that they can still be selected from the outliner, but view-port operations will ignore them.*

[image: restrict view port selection]

Comment: Now, how can I have parent objects selected if the user tries to select a child object?

Comment: How do you do this in Blender 2.8?

Comment: Note: if you don't see the arrow, click "filter" on the top part of the outliner pane and select the buttons you want in "Restriction Toggles".